# Cordova/Phonegap android hash key

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I am writing an application using Cordova/Phonegap (current 3.5) and am running into a problem trying to integrate the Facebook plugin that you can get at https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

I understand that I need to add a hash key to my Facebook developer account (release and debug mode) and have done this following the processes outlined at http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

I build and push my app to android using Cordova build android or Phonegap build android and the app is happily built and pushed to my phone.

The app is running along and the plugin API is working because it opens up the facebook app to authenticate but I get the error message. Facebook Invalid key hash. The key hash xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at etc..

I have tried manually dropping the debug-unaligned, debug, release-unsigned and release onto my phone and I still get the same message from Facebook. I have manually signed my unsigned release with a key from a release store following a guide, I verified it was signed..put the key on facebook. Still no joy!

I think that I am completely missing something but have read multiple blogs, guides and posts on StackOverflow and can't get this to work. Can anyone help me out or point me in the right direction?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the hash key seems to change on each build. This is because the facebook error changes the key that isn't recognised.

Comment: Did you create application in (https://developers.facebook.com/apps)